# Make objdump use an operand-size suffix like l on every mnemonic, even when it's not ambiguous?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, att, objdump

Today, I found out about using objdump in Linux to find the disassembled code of programs in At&t syntax. While using objdump, the disassembled code looked fine but lacked the 'l' ending after the mnemonic (It should be "movl" not "mov"). Is there any way I can configure objdump to fix this issue?

The current disassembled program generated:

```
stuff:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08049000 <_start>:
 8049000:   eb 00                   jmp    8049002 <print_stuff>

08049002 <print_stuff>:
 8049002:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 8049007:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 804900c:   b9 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%ecx
 8049011:   ba 0b 00 00 00          mov    $0xb,%edx
 8049016:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8049018:   eb 00                   jmp    804901a <end_program>

0804901a <end_program>:
 804901a:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 804901f:   bb 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%ebx
 8049024:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

What I want it to look like:

```
stuff:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08049000 <_start>:
 8049000:   eb 00                   jmp     8049002 <print_stuff>

08049002 <print_stuff>:
 8049002:   b8 04 00 00 00          movl    $0x4,%eax
 8049007:   bb 01 00 00 00          movl    $0x1,%ebx
 804900c:   b9 05 00 00 00          movl    $0x5,%ecx
 8049011:   ba 0b 00 00 00          movl    $0xb,%edx
 8049016:   cd 80                   int     $0x80
 8049018:   eb 00                   jmp     804901a <end_program>

0804901a <end_program>:
 804901a:   b8 01 00 00 00          movl    $0x1,%eax
 804901f:   bb 05 00 00 00          movl    $0x5,%ebx
 8049024:   cd 80                   int     $0x80
```

Comment: `mov    $0x4,%eax` is valid AT&T syntax, omitting the operand-size suffix when it's implied by a register operand.  I updated your title to be more specific, assuming that's really what you want for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clutter your output with redundant suffixes even when it's implied by a register operand, use

```
objdump -d -M suffix  foo
```

From [the `objdump(1)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html):

> "`suffix`"
> When in AT&T mode and also for a limited set of instructions when in Intel mode, instructs the
> disassembler to print a mnemonic suffix even when the suffix could be inferred by the operands or, for
> certain instructions, the execution mode's defaults.

---

BTW, the "limited subset of Intel syntax" includes instructions like relative `jmp rel32`, e.g.

```
$ objdump -d -M intel /bin/ls
   ...
    436e:       e9 12 fe ff ff          jmp    4185 <__cxa_atexit@plt+0x155>

$ objdump -d -M intel,suffix /bin/ls
   ...
    436e:       e9 12 fe ff ff          jmpq   4185 <__cxa_atexit@plt+0x155>
```

(Related: [What is callq instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752964/what-is-callq-instruction) - `objdump -Mintel` prints `callq` / `retq` even without the `suffix` option.)

The intel-syntax effect doesn't include instructions like `add` or `mov` or even `movzx`.  With a memory operand, they'd explicitly indicate size as `qword ptr [rdi]` for example, and objdump does always include that even when it's implied by the other operand.